# How to write a RegEx finding ` (Grave accent) surrounding a string not containing ${ variable }

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regular expression that finds *grave accents* that surround a string, but not if that string contains `${ someVar }`.

```js
const twoMatch = `test string`;
const noMatches = `test ${ variabel }`;
```

This would be good to easily replace the grave accents with regular apostrophes.

Comment: Neither `twoMatch` nor `noMatches` contain any.

Comment: Im not searching inside the string values, I want to use the IDE search to find the Grave accents surrounding, and thus defining it is a string value.

Comment: So you've opened the JS file as text and are searching through that? --- `'' === \`\` // true`

Comment: I'm opening the JS file (actually TS in this case) in Visual Studio Code. And using the search to find the grave accents.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: Sure, it helps. But it requires me to do the thinking ;).
Actually I'm working on it and when I have an answer I will of course share it here :).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
(?<!.*\${.*)(\b\w+\b)(?!.*}.*)
```

explain :

```
(?<!.*\${.*) : not precided by '${' in any place
(?!.*}.*) : not followed by '}' in any place
\b : word boundry
\w+ : 1 or more character [a-zA-z0-9_]
```

[**demo**](https://regexr.com/5g5dj)

Comment: Looks very promising! I tried it in the IDE (Visual Studio Code) but it complains it is invalid "Incomplete quantifier".

Comment: But on the second look, it matches the string and not the grace accents. I'm far from confident this is possible with an regex. Might need some code. Like a linter rule.

Comment: In computing I think the term for \` is “back-tick” or “backquote”